# How to add class on ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I have this: http://plnkr.co/edit/gJko3umteXXEye7o9StR?p=preview

How can i add class "active-link" on:

```
@Translate("PERSONAL_INFORMATION") 
@Translate("NOTIFICATIONS") 
@Translate("CHANGE_PASSWORD") 
@Translate("GAME_SETTINGS")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using classes like `active-link`, `x-y` which have `dash (-)` then you have to wrap it in `'` as below.

```
ng-class="{'active-link' : activeLink==='PersonalInfo'}"
```

if your classes like `activeLink` which are doesn't have `dash (-)` then you can avoid from `'` but not a must.

```
ng-class="{activeLink : activeLink==='PersonalInfo'}"
```

here is the updated [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jDdFIKWDtYkzaX1OMnlT?p=preview)

Comment: ha ha thanks :) and glad to help you again. cheerz :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an ng-class to your element

```
<div ng-click="setClass()" ng-class="class">@Translate("NOTIFICATIONS")</div>
```

and change the value in your function

```
$scope.setClass(new function(){
    $scope.class = "active-link";
})
```